# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When I'm trying to lookup a record by field name `uuid` I'm getting below error:

{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[SyncBank.Models.XeroBankAccount]' to type 'SyncBank.Models.XeroBankAccount'

```
public XeroBankAccount FindAccountByUuid(String uuid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SyncBankDbContext dbContext = new SyncBankDbContext())
                {
                    string tempUuid = uuid;
                    var result = (XeroBankAccount) dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.Where(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid);
                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errorMessage = e.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[SyncBank.Models.XeroBankAccount]' to type 'SyncBank.Models.XeroBankAccount'."}
```

XeroBankAccount.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using SyncBank.Xero;

namespace SyncBank.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    [Table("xero_bank_account")]
    public class XeroBankAccount
    {

        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("XeroOrganisation")]
        [Column("organisation_id")]
        public int XeroOrganisationId { get; set; }

        public XeroOrganisation XeroOrganisation { get; set; }

        [Column("bank_id")]
        public int? BankId { get; set; }


        [Column("title")]
        [MinLength(1), MaxLength(128)]
        [Required]
        public String AccountTitle { get; set; }

        [Column("number")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public String AccountNumber { get; set; }

        [Column("balance_statement")]
        public double? BalanceStatement { get; set; }

        [Column("balance_xero")]
        public double? BalanceXero { get; set; }

        [Column("last_statement_date")]
        public DateTime? LastStatementDate { get; set; }

        [Column("reconciled")]
        public BankAccountReconciled? Reconciled { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("uuid")]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string AccountUuid { get; set; }

        [Column("orders")]
        public int Orders { get; set; }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
            if (!(obj is XeroBankAccount))
            {
                return false;
            }
            XeroBankAccount other = (XeroBankAccount)obj;
            return Id == other.Id;
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return "org.syncbank.entity.XeroBankAccount[ accountId=" + Id + " ]";
        }
    }
}
```

SQL xero_bank_account:

```
CREATE TABLE `xero_bank_account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `organisation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bank_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance_statement` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance_xero` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reconciled` enum('true','false') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
  `last_statement_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `orders` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `xero_bank_account`
--
ALTER TABLE `xero_bank_account`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `account_uuid` (`uuid`),
  ADD KEY `account_title_caption` (`number`),
  ADD KEY `bank_id` (`bank_id`);
```

Comment: `var result = dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid);`

Comment: Your result is an a collection not an object.

Comment: Sorry, initial error was solved, the issue when I use Linq I get {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Comment: You can't just change your post to be a completely new question.

Comment: @DavidG My mistake sorry

Comment: I have rolled it back.

Comment: I was editing my question and I hit the submit by mistake, answers came in faster than I can edit my question! sorry about that

Comment: @DavidG Please delete the question

Comment: why using SingleOrDefault, just use FirstOrDefault

Comment: @NaDeRStar Single is better than First if you expect there to be a single result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to cast collection of `XeroBankAccount` to the single object of `XeroBankAccount` by using `.Where()` lambda expression so that's why you got an cast exception.

If you want to get your query must return single object of `XeroBankAccount` then, you can use any one of below

```
var result = (XeroBankAccount) dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.Where(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR

```
var result = (XeroBankAccount) dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid);
```

OR

```
var result = (XeroBankAccount) dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.Where(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I tried `var result = (XeroBankAccount) dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid` and now I'm getting : 'dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

Comment: could you please provide exact exception message?

Comment: I was editing my question and I hit the submit by mistake, answers came in faster than I can edit my question! sorry about that

Comment: error is: "Method System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[T] MergeAs(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption) contains generic parameters"`

Comment: Here is : `string tempUuid = uuid;
var result = dbContext.XeroBankAccounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AccountUuid == tempUuid);
return result;`

Comment: but beware that if you have more than 2 records with same uuid then you will get an excpetion that `Sequence contains more than one eleemnt` when you use `SingleOrDefault` so either user `.Take(1).SingleOrDefault()` or just use `FirstOrDefault()` :)